# Detectar ponto na tela com câmera do dispositivo

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca ou prática para detectar um ponto na imagem captada com a câmera do dispositivo? Ex. um papel branco com um ponto preto, então a câmera detecta esse ponto e dá as coordenadas da tela (X e Y).

Comment: Uma rotina que funciona para a imagem captada pela câmera, de fato, funciona para qualquer imagem. Nessa rotina você diria qual a cor do fundo e ela percorreria todos os pixels da imagem até encontrar os que são diferentes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391353/get-color-of-each-pixel-of-an-image-using-bufferedimages

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo vc acha que essa rotina se adapta para uso em tempo real da câmera?  como se fosse ler um qr code.

Comment: Sim. Pode ser feito. Veja esse exemplo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tsang.alan.distancemeter